# Communicate with ros through XML-RPC

Tags: ros, xmlrpc, librviz, windows10

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a project where i need to communicate to ROS from Windows PC. I found that XML-RPC is the best way to do it. Any other suggestions would be much appreciated.

My question is, can we communicate using different protocols like SOAP request to XML-RPC? Will that be feasible? I know this is a kind of weird idea but I am facing issues in linking XML-RPC libraries for C++.

Can I get the video feed from rviz(Simulation of the Robot) through XML-RPC request response procedure in order to display in Windows PC?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242037/communicate-with-ros-through-xml-rpc/) by [ghkraju](https://answers.ros.org/users/27712/ghkraju/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2016-08-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-20**:
Some clarification: XML-RPC is only used in ROS to communicate with the *master*, not with individual nodes. Data exchange between nodes is a 1-to-1 affair, and uses [TCPROS](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/TCPROS) (or its UDP variant).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-20**:\

> Can I get the video feed from rviz(Simulation of the Robot) [..]

and a bit pedantic maybe (my apologies), but RViz is *not* a simulator, it's only a *visualisation tool*. Any 'video feed' you visualise in it *must* come from another node, so to retrieve it, contact that node.

**Comment by [ghkraju](https://answers.ros.org/users/27712/ghkraju/) on 2016-08-20**:
Thank you for the comment. I have used rosbridge_server and made a connection with ROS Master (websocket and tcp). In both cases i am able to connect to ROS master with a url(http://192.168.xx.xx:9090/) but i am not sure how to call a service/node after successful connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made a successful connection between windows and Virtualbox Ubuntu using rosserial_server(http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial). This looks pretty good and I hope this suits my requirement. For video feed as suggested by gvdhoorn I will try to subscribe to that node.

---

Originally posted by [ghkraju](https://answers.ros.org/users/27712/ghkraju/) with karma: 80 on 2016-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0